# Why polygons is displaying under DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcscene, 3d-map

I am trying to create 3d buildings in ArcMap. I added SRTM, than created shape and draw on top of it few polygons and than specified to every polygon height (add and fill column height).

But when I am adding result to ArcScene polygons are drawing **under** DEM. But it should draw on it and 3D model should be on top.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your heights as z-coordinates. The program does not recognize a normal attribut as heights. Therefore you need to create a shapefile witch contains a third coordinate. When creating the shapefile you can check that option in the lower part of the first page of the creation dialog.

The you just copy your objects into the new shapefile and us the option to populate the z-coordinate by a field value. You can find the How-To in the following link:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/populating-the-z-value-using-an-attribute-value.htm